# java 9 module exception in running

Tags: java, java-9, java-module

I have download jdk 9 from  https://jdk9.java.net/download/  and Quick-start guide from  http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/quick-start#linkerJigsaw   and wrote the first example "Greetings" according to this guide. The project compiled successfully but when i trying to run i got exception

```
         E:\>java --module-path mods -m com.greetings/com.greetings.Main
    Error occurred during initialization of VM
    java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Error reading module: mods\com.greetings
    at java.lang.module.Resolver.findWithBeforeFinder(java.base@9-ea/Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.module.Resolver.resolveRequires(java.base@9-ea/Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.module.Configuration.resolveRequiresAndUses(java.base@9-ea/Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.module.ModuleDescriptor$1.resolveRequiresAndUses(java.base@9-ea/Unknown Source)
    at jdk.internal.module.ModuleBootstrap.boot(java.base@9-ea/Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.initPhase2(java.base@9-ea/Unknown Source)

    Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Main.class found in in top-level directory (unnamed package not allowed in module)
    at java.lang.module.ModuleInfo.invalidModuleDescriptor(java.base@9-ea/Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.module.ModuleInfo.read(java.base@9-ea/Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.module.ModuleDescriptor.read(java.base@9-ea/Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.module.ModulePath.readExplodedModule(java.base@9-ea/Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.module.ModulePath.readModule(java.base@9-ea/Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.module.ModulePath.scanDirectory(java.base@9-ea/Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.module.ModulePath.scan(java.base@9-ea/Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.module.ModulePath.scanNextEntry(java.base@9-ea/Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.module.ModulePath.find(java.base@9-ea/Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.module.ModuleFinder$2.lambda$find$0(java.base@9-ea/Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(java.base@9-ea/Unknown Source)
    at java.util.AbstractList$RandomAccessSpliterator.tryAdvance(java.base@9-ea/Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(java.base@9-ea/Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(java.base@9-ea/Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(java.base@9-ea/Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(java.base@9-ea/Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(java.base@9-ea/Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(java.base@9-ea/Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(java.base@9-ea/Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.module.ModuleFinder$2.find(java.base@9-ea/Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.module.Resolver.findWithBeforeFinder(java.base@9-ea/Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.module.Resolver.resolveRequires(java.base@9-ea/Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.module.Configuration.resolveRequiresAndUses(java.base@9-ea/Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.module.ModuleDescriptor$1.resolveRequiresAndUses(java.base@9-ea/Unknown Source)
    at jdk.internal.module.ModuleBootstrap.boot(java.base@9-ea/Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.initPhase2(java.base@9-ea/Unknown Source)
```

I could not find reason of this exception

Comment: It says "Main.class found in in top-level directory  -- unnamed package not allowed in module". Where did you put your main class?

Comment: I have created directory with   E:\>mkdir mods\com.greetings    and compile using  E:\>javac -d mods\com.greetings  src\com.greetings\module-info.java      and    E:\>javac -d mods\com.greetings  src\com.greetings\com\greetings\Main.java       the class files are as     E:\mods\com.greetings\module-info.class              E:\mods\com.greetings\com\greetings\Main.class

Comment: What's the source code for Main.java look like?